# Magnetic field in the center of a coil

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, electromagnetic

I have a closed core with a coil attached to it and metal inside the core. The N is 100, I is 100mA and l = 300mm. I have computed the magnetic field B = (μ0 * μr * N * I) / l. But I have also given area A = 2cm^2 of the core, should I take that into account somehow?

[image]

Comment: B is a flux density. How does the area affect a density across it? What is the product of area and density?

Comment: @Neil_UK Thank you for your answer. Magnetic flux is the product of A (area) and B (magnetic ffield) , but how can magnetic flux help me with calculating the magnetic field in the center of the coil ?